# Multi tenant application with ASP.NET Core 3.0 and EF Core

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-4

I'm developing a multi-tenant based application that will have a separate database for each school/tenant. Each schema will be identical to each other. The idea is to have one database context using .NET Core 3 and EF Core.

For example, the client navigates to school1.gov.uk, then SchoolContext is instantiated using the connection strings stored in appsettings.json under 'school1'.

Currently, I'm having to run add-migration against every new context added. Can anyone come up with a solution to run migrations once, under a single context i.e. SchoolContext ?

Main Context

```
public class SchoolContext : DbContext
{     protected readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
      private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }

    public SchoolContext(IConfiguration configuration, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) 
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
            var subdomain = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Host.Host;
            var connectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString(subdomain);
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
    }

}
```

Tenant Context 1

```
public class School1Context : SchoolContext
{
    public Schoo1Context()
    {

    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
         var connectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString("School1");
         optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
    }

}
```

Tenant Context 2

```
public class School2Context : SchoolContext
{
    public School2Context()
    {

    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
         var connectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString("School2");
         optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
    }

}
```

Program.cs

```
         using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
         {
             var school1Context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<School1Context>();
             school1Context.Database.Migrate();
             var school2Context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<School2Context>();
             school2Context.Database.Migrate();
         }
```

Appsettings.json

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "School1": "Persist Security Info=true;Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=School1;User ID=;Password=;",
    "School2": "Persist Security Info=true;Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=School2;User ID=;Password=;",

   }
```

Comment: https://codewithmukesh.com/blog/multitenancy-in-aspnet-core/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The biggest problem I see with your code is that you should have 1 context (because they're all the same schema, right?). If they had different schemas, you would need different contexts.

That single context should be instantiated with the **school's specific connection string**.

This way, you add-migration against 1 context (not multiple).

You're mostly there, just delete School1Context and School2Context, because here:

SchoolContext.cs

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
   var subdomain = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Host.Host;
   var connectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString(subdomain); // <--- this is tenanted already
   optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
}
```

You already grab the connection string and connect to a different database.

You stated the answer in your original question:

> The idea is to have one database context using .NET Core 3 and EF
>   Core.

Slight plug to a framework I love and use daily: ServiceStack has multitenancy built in - [ServiceStack Multitenancy](https://docs.servicestack.net/multitenancy)

Comment: From what I get from the OP he needs his app to reference all the DBs in all _schools_

Comment: That's not my understanding. This statement: "For example, the client navigates to school1.gov.uk, then SchoolContext is instantiated using the connection strings stored in appsettings.json under 'school1'." This tells me he only needs to access School 1's database when people visit school1.gov.uk. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: and wouldn't it even be better to have multiple deployment profiles and config transformations while keeping the app EXACTLY the same (using same connectionString key) for all the hosts?

Answer (score 5):

I encountered almost the same problem with yours. I have one TenantDbContext.

```
public class TenantDbContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly Tenant _tenant;

    public DbSet<Branch> Branches { get; set; }

    public TenantDbContext(DbContextOptions<TenantDbContext> options, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        : base(options)
    {
        if (httpContextAccessor.HttpContext != null)
        {
            _tenant = (Tenant)httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Items["TENANT"];
        }
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (_tenant != null)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_tenant.ConnectionString);
        }

        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }
}
```

Then I found it's hard to "Add-Migration" using Package Manager Console, because the connection string is dynamic, so I created a place-holder ("Dev") for the connection string, in Startup.ConfigureServices()

```
var devConnectionString = _config.GetConnectionString("Dev");
services.AddDbContext<TenantDbContext>(opt => opt.UseSqlServer(devConnectionString));
```

You know, there are two ways to configure a DbContext, as shown in two code snippets above respectively. If both are supplied, the AddDbContext() will be called first, and then OnConfiguring() will be called additionally.

When you run the "Add-Migration" command, migrations will be generated in a DbContext with the placeholder connection string, although there's no tenant specified. When you run your application, you just need to add a middleware and call Migrate() to apply those migrations onto your tenant DBs, before you go to the MVC middleware.

```
public class TenantIdentifier
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public TenantIdentifier(RequestDelegate next, IConfiguration configuration, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _next = next;
        _configuration = configuration;
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, HostDbContext hostDbContext)
    {
        // Get tenant id from token
        var tenantId = httpContext.User.FindFirst(Constants.TENANT)?.Value;

        // Set tenant id to httpContext.Items
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tenantId))
        {
            var tenant = hostDbContext.Tenants.SingleOrDefault(t => t.Id.ToString() == tenantId);
            httpContext.Items["TENANT"] = tenant;

            using(var tenantDbContext = new TenantDbContext(new DbContextOptions<TenantDbContext>(), _httpContextAccessor))
            {
                tenantDbContext.Database.Migrate();
            }
        }

        await _next.Invoke(httpContext);
    }
}
```

Then, you just need to run "Add-Migration" once, without the placeholder DB created at all.