# Connect to multiple databases with different servers using Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Is it possible or how could I achieve this scenario with EF core? For example our company have an API made in asp net core and we have a main Database ( we are using EF using Context) where store all data from our clients like names, last names, database name, server name, port number, etc and currently I am developing an app using Maui and I am going to consume that company API using httpclient but I don't know how to make that API (I have access to this code) to redirect or connect to many databases from different clients and it can be 500 or 1000 or 2000 clients with different server names and creating a Context for each client would be tired and tedious and would me take 10 months or more.

Is there a way to make this easier using EF core? like making the server name, port name, database name like dynamic? How could I solve this? Does EF have a built up tools for this?

or

Should I use `SqlClient` for this issue? (I found this easier since I can easily modify server name easily)

PD: all clients databases are the same, the only thing that changes is the server name and the port and of course the password to access.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a detailed description on how you currently set the connection string for your EF context.

Comment: How the app pass the ID client to the API?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multi tenant application with ASP.NET Core 3.0 and EF Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59996324/multi-tenant-application-with-asp-net-core-3-0-and-ef-core)

Comment: oh yes it answers my question in fact I forgot to mention "multi-tentant", but there can be many different databases from different server names.

Comment: @Progman there is no need to give code here. I think you did not get the SO question well, I think I better explain better next time.

Comment: You can achive multitenancy easily by using finbuckle lib: https://www.finbuckle.com/MultiTenant/Docs/