# How to connect ASP.NET Core site to Master and Slave at the same time using Pomelo EF Core Driver?

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

I have a master and a slave replica MySQL server that I want to connect via my ASP.NET Core application. My connection string is like this:

```
server=master.domain.com, slave.domain.com;port=3306;user=user;password=mysosecretpassword;database=mydb
```

However, my SELECT queries are not hitting the slave server. (I have tested it with a poor man's check, changing data on the slave by hand and checking it out on my application. I only see the master data)

Am I doing something wrong? Can't find anything related to master slave connection using Pomelo drivers.

Comment: Hi @platypus, Does this answer your question? [Multi tenant application with ASP.NET Core 3.0 and EF Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59996324/multi-tenant-application-with-asp-net-core-3-0-and-ef-core).

Comment: My case is a bit different. I am looking to connect master and slave at the same time. The slave is the replicated version of the master. So I can offload read operations to the slaves. I don't want to switch DB connection strings. Just want to provide master and slave connections at the start.

Comment: From documentation: `Each new connection tries to connect to the first host; subsequent hosts are used only if connecting to the first one fails. This is the default if Pooling=False.`

Comment: @GeorgRichter So it looks like we always have to have a reverse proxy in front of our slave master clusters that we need to connect to. Without a reverse proxy then there is no way scaling traffic in a round robin way. Correct me if I am wrong please.

Comment: @platypus Yes, you need a proxy e.g. MaxScale which handles parsing, load balancing but also fail over.